# Migrating existing Karate project from Version 0.8.0 to 0.9.5 - Folder structure to use

Tags: karate

I'm currently trying to migrate existing Karate project from 0.8.0.1 to 0.9.5 but facing some issues like below

1. Folder Structure to use

Attached is the current structure of my project, I have feature files in both testFeatures and utilsFeatures which are required by my tests

2. Current cucumber runner class

```html
@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:resources/testFeatures",
        plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json" },
        tags = { "~@ignore" })
```

3. if I want to migrate to new version of karate(0.9.5) without re-ordering the folder structure
   using new Karate runner - how would i go about it ?

[image]

4.Karate runner file

```html
@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:resources/testFeatures/", tags = {"~ignore"} )
public class GraphQLFunctionalKarateRunner {
}
```

5. when i use the above, it is missing the files from utlsFeatures folder
   and i want to if i can manage the folder (existing folder structure) with pom?
6. POM.xml file

   com.intuit.karate
           karate-apache
           0.8.0.1
           test

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
       <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
       <version>0.8.0.1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <!--    removed maven   from reference maven-cucumber-reporting                  -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.0</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
       <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
       <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.12</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

   src/test/java
               
                   **/*.java
               
           
           
               src/test/java/resources/
               .

   ```
   <plugins>


       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
           <configuration>
               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
               <source>${java.version}</source>
               <target>${java.version}</target>
               <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.20</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.0</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>execution</id>
                   <phase>verify</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>generate</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <projectName>reportingTest</projectName>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                       <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/</cucumberOutput>
                       <parallelTesting>true</parallelTesting>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```

   run-tests
           
               
                   
                       org.apache.maven.plugins
                       maven-surefire-plugin
                       2.20
                       
                           
                               functional/GraphQLFunctionalTestRunnerParallel.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate doesn't support the `CucumberOptions` so please refer to the change-log and make the changes: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases

There is no need for the annotation also. The problem may be because of your Maven setup. So please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter .... can I keep my existing folder structure as is and migrate to 0.9.5 ?

Comment: @AnilKumarNagisetty really cannot say without seeing all your code, but in general: Yes

Comment: Thanks again ... i am attaching my karate project pom.xml file for you while i am creating the dummy project as suggested.

Comment: @AnilKumarNagisetty sorry that's not enough, I insist on the process